# GPS coordinates not working in blackberry 9800 using webworks

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry, geolocation, blackberry-webworks

I am using HTML5 Geo-location API for getting the GPS cordinates

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, 
                                     [geolocationError], 
                                     [geolocationOptions]);
```

This is working in all version except Blackberry 9800. I am using the api in blackberry webworks . Could somebody help me out, whether blackberry 9800 supports the above api, or I have to do something else.

Or can anyone tell me any blackberry webworks extension for Geolocation.

Answer (score 2):

That's the correct way to retrieve GPS coordinates in a BlackBerry WebWorks app.

Confirm that your device can retrieve GPS coordinates in general. If it works on some devices except one, then I think its a connectivity issue.  Try this:

1) Open Settings --> Device --> Location Settings
2) Make sure the "Location Services" is set to 'On'.
3) Open the menu, and select "Refresh Location"

You should see the GPS coordinates populated in the 'Location' section of this screen.  These values will be sent to the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() method.  If these values remain empty, then your app will get empty values too.

Hope that helps.